# Can a IAM user create another "sub" IAM user himself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As an Admin user, I have created an IAM user with some restricted accesses for testing purposes.

So, when I login with the IAM user, I don't have access to unauthorized services as expected but I've noticed that I can create and remove IAM users, even if I didn't created them by myself.

So, I have three questions:

1. Why an IAM have the ability to remove other users?
2. And how can I prevent this?
3. When an IAM user create "sub IAM users", do these "sub users" inherit from his unauthorizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user is granted the ability to create a user by virtue of the permissions granted to the first user. If you attach a policy to the second her that also grants the ability to create users that second will have permission to do so. There is a feature that allows you to grant a user the permission to create other uses whilst limiting the permissions of the second user. The feature is called [Permission boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html). By using this you can allow a user to create other users but limit what permissions that other user can grant.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Why an IAM have the ability to remove other users?

Am IAM user is just another user of your AWS account. It appears you gave the new IAM user the permissions to create, modify, or delete other IAM user accounts.

> 2) And how can I prevent this ?

You need to review the IAM policies and roles assigned to the new IAM user and remove the permissions you don't want them to have. Please post the exact IAM roles and policies you have assigned to the user if you need help with this.

> 3) When an IAM user create "sub IAM users", do these "sub users"
>   inherit from his unauthorizations ?

There is no such thing as "sub users". A user is not in any way tied to the user that created them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "sub-IAM users." An IAM user is an IAM user. The user has permissions to create other IAM users because you haven't denied the `iam:*` policies. You said you "created an IAM user with some restricted accesses for testing purposes." Without seeing the user it's not possible to know what permissions you have granted, but you must have allowed IAM permissions. To prevent the user from creating other users, do not attach policies that allow the `iam:CreateUser` permission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right an IAM user shouldn't have the ability to manage other users. AWS has policies for this like if you want other users to give access to all services you can create a group and attach **PowerUserAccessPolicy** to that group. Users with **PowerUserAccess** wouldn't be able to manage groups and other IAM users. Further, if you want to restrict admin users access to manage other IAM users you can create custom policy to **deny** this affect using an inline policy.

**Reference:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Any IAM user can't be called as "sub-user", as all users can be said to have the same level.When any IAM user is associated the policies for IAM operations such as create, update, delete, that user can perform such IAM operations for new or existing users.